# One word for "Unseen but felt" or maybe a better expression to denote the exact meaning?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, expressions, synonyms, vocabulary

Romantic relationships and sexual activeness are also sensitive areas where competition among men is unseen but felt.

Comment: You can smell the testosterone in the air!

Comment: Romantic relationships and sexual activeness are also sensitive areas where competition among men is "observed".

Comment: I would mention that there is a large visual element to this palpable atmosphere of romantic relationship and sexual activity, but that it can be subtle--even subliminal.

Answer (score 5):

*[Palpable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/palpable)*:

> 1.1 (Especially of a feeling or atmosphere) so intense as to be almost touched or felt:
>
> ODO

From [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=palpable&allowed_in_frame=0):

> late 14c., "that can be touched,"
>   from Late Latin palpabilis "that
>   may be touched or felt,"
>   from Latin palpare "touch gently, stroke"
>   (see feel (v.)).
>   Figurative sense of "easily perceived, evident"
>   also is from late 14c.   Related: Palpably.
>
> *[feel](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=feel&allowed_in_frame=0)* (v.)
>
> Old English felan "to touch or have a sensory experience of; perceive,
>   sense (something)," in late Old English "have a mental perception,"
>   from Proto-Germanic *foljan (cognates: Old Saxon gifolian, Old Frisian
>   fela, Dutch voelen, Old High German vuolen, German fühlen "to feel,"
>   Old Norse falma "to grope"), from PIE root *pal- "to touch, feel,
>   shake, strike softly" (cognates: Greek psallein "to pluck (the harp),"
>   Latin palpare "to touch softly, stroke," palpitare "to move quickly"),
>   perhaps ultimately imitative.
>
> The meaning in Old English was "to perceive through senses which are
>   not referred to any special organ." Sense of "be conscious of a
>   tactile sensation, sense pain, pleasure, illness, etc.; have an
>   emotional experience or reaction," developed by c.1200, also "have an
>   opinion or conviction;" that of "to react with sympathy or compassion"
>   is from mid-14c. Meaning "to try by touch" is from early 14c. From
>   late 14c. as "know (something) beforehand, to have foreknowledge of."
>   To feel like "want to" attested from 1829.

From *[General George E. Pickett in Life and Legend](https://books.google.com/books?id=pN1Ykbet1icC&pg=RA1-PT59&dq=%22palpable%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tmQVVdmSHarIsAS22IHoBA&ved=0CCIQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=%22palpable%22&f=false)*, by Lesley J. Gordon:

> *An unchaperoned white southern woman journeying with her baby, she experienced a palpable sense of fear: “Perhaps no timid little waif thrown out upon the deep sea of life ever felt more utterly desolate.*

From [*If They Move... Kill 'Em!: The Life and Times of Sam Peckinpah*](https://books.google.com/books?id=C6J17sT7qHYC&pg=PA411&dq=%22palpable%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YmIVVfetF8KbgwSmt4OIDQ&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22palpable%22&f=false), by David Weddle:

> *As soon as she walked into the room he felt it: a palpable sensuality
>   and, just beneath it, the claws of a wildcat.*

Comment: A palpable sensuality would be evident, visible.

Comment: Conceded, @Josh61, that is not the best example! Especially for us men, sensuality is a highly visible notion.

Comment: Palpable is the word I thought of as I read the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Only single-word answer that comes to my mind is *present*.

*Romantic relationships and sexual activeness are also sensitive areas where competition among men is present.*

If you'll settle for a multiple word answer then idiom *In the air* might be good.

> able to be felt or noticed

[TFD definition](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+air)

Comment: +1 for present.  With "present" the sentence could actually be shortened even further: "Romantic relationships and sexual activeness are also sensitive areas where[ever] men are present."

Answer (score 1):

"Below the surface" might work for an alternative phrase and perhaps [subliminal](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/subliminal) for a single word

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much that the competition  is "unseen but felt", it is definitely acted out in many subtle and not-so-subtle ways, as sociologists have chronicled.

It's the **sense** of competition that is felt, but never talked about. There is an **unstated** emotional **undercurrent**, a **tacit** competitiveness; a **primal urge** to outdo one another in attracting and keeping a mate, that results in **instinctive**, **animalistic** behaviors **triggered** by subtle **cues**.

As others have mentioned, this is partly **subliminal**, below the level of rational thought, as if based on **sense of smell** (which it partly is; the comment about smelling the testosterone is not far off at all).